# What should a conversion candidate expect at an Orthodox beit din?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, beit-din-court, orthodox

[This question about conversion before a Reform *beit din*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55170/472) made me wonder about other cases: what does the examination of a prospective *ger* by an Orthodox *beit din* look like today?  Does the *beit din* test the *ger's* knowledge, or will that have been done in advance?  Do they ask the *ger* questions about his motivations?  What else?  Do they require demonstration of any skills (e.g. *davening*)?

My only point of reference is what I know about how the Reform movement does it (see the linked question), and I'm now curious about how the *beit din's* examination differs between them and others.  (Obviously what are considered satisfactory answers or kosher members will differ; I'm not asking about that.)

Comment: my friend had to learn hilchos of muktze, and he was asked halachic questions about it.

Comment: Specifics - like when an examination may be done - may differ from Beis Din to Beis Din. Therefore, I can't give you a single answer. Suffice it to say that the primary concern of the Beis Din is the potential convert's sincerity and willingness to accept and abide by Torah law in its entirety.

Answer (score 2):

many will provide a list of information the candidate must know. there will be a specific rabbi they are working with to learn these things and a specific rabbi from the beis din who will keep track of progress. on the day of the conversion they will ask some questions.by this time they will be sure the candidate will be able to answer but will do so as part of the formality of the day. From a close friend who went through a conversion with an orthodox bes din